# Serialising a python object with generic type leads to an error

Tags: python, json

I am trying to use python json library to serialise a custom object with generic type but I get an error saying `'mappingproxy' object has no attribute '__dict__'`.

My class is

```
import json
from typing import TypeVar
from typing import Generic
from toolbox.error.error import Error
from toolbox.extension.json import JsonEncoder

T = TypeVar('T')

class Result(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, is_success: bool, payload: T = None, error: Error = None):
        self.isSuccess: bool = is_success
        if is_success:
            self.successPayload: T = payload
        else:
            self.failedPayload: Error = error
```

and the JsonEncoder is

```
class JsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        else:
            return obj.__dict__
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

and Error class is

```
class Error:
    def __init__(self, error_code: str, error_message: str = None):
        self.errorCode = error_code
        self.payload = error_message
```

The failed example is

```
json.dumps(Result[str](True, "1.0.0"), cls=GenericJSONEncoder)
```

and the succeeded example is

```
json.dumps("1.0.0", cls=GenericJSONEncoder)
```

Can anyone please help to identify the issue?

Thank you

============================================================

**UPDATE**

I used another approach mentioned in https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/f4d9a0c9c8f712ec31b993034bc5f5a1, but get the same result

```
class GenericJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            return super().default(obj)
        except TypeError:
            pass
        cls = type(obj)
        result = {
            '__custom__': True,
            '__module__': cls.__module__,
            '__name__': cls.__name__,
            'data': obj.__dict__ if not hasattr(cls, '__json_encode__') else obj.__json_encode__
        }
        return result
```

Comment: `np.ndarray` aren't the only thing that don't have a `__dict__`, and note that `return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)` is unreachable.

Comment: Thank you jonrsharpe for pointing out. I find another piece of code today to serialise object with generic type (attached in the question), but still get the same error, can you please take another look? Thank you